# Full-Text Search ordered by exact match in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, exact-match

I have a query like

```
select * from mytable where posttext @@ to_tsquery('Intelence');
```

I have texts with 'intelence' word and with 'intel'.

I want to return results where exact match of the keyword 'Intelence' will be ordered before results with 'intel' ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not most optimal and performant way, but using regex match in `order by` should do what you want

```
with mytable( posttext ) as(
select 'a Intelence' union all
select 'intel someIntelence' union all
select 'a intel' union all
select 'a Intelence b' 
)

select * 
from mytable 
where posttext @@ to_tsquery('Intelence')  
order by posttext ~* '(^|\s)intelence(\s|$)' desc
```